# format date in java to 20160623_1125

Tags: java

I am using below code to format my date in the format 20160623_1123

but the month part is generating minute :

```
    long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm");
    Date resultdate = new Date(milliseconds);
    System.out.println("Formatted timestamp : "+ resultdate)
```

**Result : 20162523_1125 instead of 20160623_1125**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The code you've shown wouldn't give that output - and you're not even *using* `sdf`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: (When you use `sdf.format(resultdate)`, you should get the expected output - and I do...)

Comment: @gogoru: That post is irrelevant. The OP wants to format, not parse.

Comment: Sorry some problem with my compilation...its working

Comment: I suggest you delete the question in that case.

Comment: Cannot delete as it has answers and need moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MyClass {
    private final static SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm");

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("Formatted timestamp : " + SDF.format(new Date()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm");
    Date resultdate = new Date(milliseconds);
    System.out.println("Formatted timestamp : "+ sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disturb the class **System** to get the current time in milliseconds.
First of all you need to get your actual date trough the class **Date** and then format it trough the **SimpleDateFormat**

This is the code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date today = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm");
        String date = sdf.format(today);
        System.out.println("Formatted timestamp : " + date);
    }

}
```